# How can I compare change in means over time?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, k-means

I have a data set showing a change in a specific score for a certain group of people over time. I measured the score at 3, 4, 6 and 12 months. Thus, I have the score for each person of the 30 people over these periods. How can I calculate if the change of the mean score from 3 months to 1 year was statistically significant or not?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, this is a simple repeated measure experiment with 30 respondents.

You may want to use paired t-test or Wilcoxon signed-rank test.